When pushing code to a remote repo on GitHub, what's the difference between adding a file to .gitignore and just not staging it for commit?
I'm pretty new to version control and getting the hang of pushing code from my local repos to remote ones on GitHub.  In the past I have mostly just staged all files for commit, and specified the ones that I don't want to show up in my remote repo inside a .gitignore file.  However, I was wondering if the same can be accomplished by just selectively staging the files I want to add or update?
I hope my phrasing here makes sense.  I've tried to search for an existing answer to this question but could not find a clear verdict.  Thanks.

I think you could do the same by "selectively staging the files you want to add or update" ... as long as you do so every time, without fail, for the life of your project, and of course everyone else who touches the repo is as careful as well. I think one of the nice things about git ignores is you can automatically ignore files without having to think about it so much - build artifacts, for instance.

git add FileA will only stage FileA; if you commit from there, then changes to FileB will not be in that commit. However, while that isn't a foolproof method - someone might not know that FileB shouldn't be committed, or they might forget, or whatever, and then FileB is in the repo with all its nonpublic detail.
If FileB is in .gitignore, though, then it won't be in any commits (even if you run git add FileB). The big gotcha here is that .gitignore is not retroactive - if FileB is already being tracked in the repo, then adding it to .gitignore will have no effect. (That's why it isn't called .gitforget.)
In practice, I think .gitignore is going to be a better long-term thing for you, if only because it doesn't rely on humans to do the right thing. You should still consider git add FileA (or a space-separated list of files to add) for making more focused commits, though.

Thanks for the thorough response Jim!  Much appreciated :)
